# Appending specific data from csv file into seperate python lists

Tags: python, excel, list, csv

I am having a bit of trouble trying to figure out how to separate two sets of data I have in a `CSV` file into two separate `lists` in python

Basically, I have scores for a game in an Excel document in this format:

```
ROUND 1
Player 1, 3, Player 4, 6
Player 2, 4, Player 5, 9
Player 3, 6, Player 6, 2
ROUND 2
Player 1, 3, Player 4, 6
Player 2, 4, Player 5, 9
Player 3, 6, Player 6, 2
```

Also in the same file I have the scores for 'Round 2' which is in the same format and I'm basically wanting to store the data for round 1 and round 2 into two different lists in python. I have managed to read through the csv file and append this data to a list however, it appends both sets of data into the same list which is not the desired effect. Is there a way I can for example, add the data from the csv file into a list until it reads "Round 2" and then it'll begin adding the data to another list if that makes sense?

Here is my code so far, but it doesn't switch `lists`:

```
round1Scores = []
round2Scores = []
with open(roundScores) as csvfile:
     for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
        round1Scores.append(row)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is difficult for me to understand your question since you do not show us any sample data, and I do not understand your template. Please show us sample data files, the desired output, the output you are getting now, and why that output is wrong. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I will try to clarify the data set. So I have an excel file and the first column contains different players such as "Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3" etc. The second column has the score for players and each players score will be in the same row as the player. This format is then repeated in the next two columns to represent the opposing player and their score. Then below this I have done the same thing again for scores for 'round 2'. I basically want to read the first round of scores into a list and then the second round of scores into a second list

Comment: Basically what I am asking is, is there a way I can read the data from the first round of scores into a python list and as the file is being read through eventually it'll hit a cell that contains "Round 2", at which point I want to stop adding data to the first list and start adding it to the second. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this literally by switching `list` you `append` to when you reach `"ROUND 2"`, just use a `variable`...

```
round1Scores = []
round2Scores = []
round = 1
with open(roundScores) as csvfile:
     for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
         if "ROUND 2" in row:
             round = 2
         if round == 1:
             round1Scores.append(row)
         elif round == 2:
             round2Scores.append(row)
```

Comment: Awesome it works! I appreciate the help man I didn't realise it was as simple as adding a variable and using the statement "If Round 2 in row" :)

Comment: @SeanCampbell Please `accept` and `up-vote` as that how this site works! Glad I could help!